# SQL Server 8111 - but column is NOT NULLABLE

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

I want to add a primary key constraint to an existing column on an existing table that contains data.  The column is not nullable.

However, when I call

```
alter table mytable add primary key (mycolumn)
```

I get an 8111:

> Msg 8111, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Cannot define PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint on nullable column in table 'mytable'

Even if I call both instructions in a row:

```
alter table mytable alter column mycolumn INT NOT NULL;
alter table mytable add primary key (mycolumn)
```

I still get an 8111 
 - and the column description in SQL Server Management Studio confirms, that mycolumn is set to NOT NULL

What can I do this?

Comment: Try putting `GO` between the two commands or running them separately. This is a parsing issue, not order of operations.

Comment: The table exists and there is already data before trying to add the new column. What should the PK have for data? Do you want it to be an Identity column? Specify the Identity (1,1) and that should solve your issue. If not, then I think you may need a staging table for this.

Comment: @WEI_DBA No, the column already exists.

Comment: @AaronBertrand. Misuderstood. I thought he was trying to add the new column.

Comment: can you provide a repro for us to test,i mean your  table definition

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate your batches. It would be best to include the schema name as well.

```
alter table dbo.mytable alter column mycolumn INT NOT NULL;
go
alter table dbo.mytable add primary key (mycolumn);
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/TZLEWP56616

Comment: as I said, the second command does not work alone either, and mycolumn is supposed to be set on 'not null'.

Comment: @Ferenjito Any chance this is a schema issue? Do you have a table with the same name in a different schema?

Comment: @Ferenjito I can't reproduce. You're going to have to provide more details.